# Image path to image not working with jar

Tags: java, jar

I have created a jar for my java application. This program takes 4 inputs from the user from the command line. Below is the syntax to invoke my application:

```
java -jar myJar.jar input1 input2 input3 input4
```

Now the input1 is the path to an image and input2 is the path to a directory. When I run the jar, it says image not found. But when I run this from eclipse with the inputs, it runs fine. Is there anything I should be aware of? I am writing the following code in the my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        File file1 = new File(args[0]);
        File file2 = new File(args[1]);

        if (!file1.exists() || !file2.exists() || !args[2].equals("abc")){
            System.out.println("Error in input, please check");
        }

        else if(checkInput(args[3])==false){

                System.out.println("Error");

        }

        else if(checkInput(args[3])==true){
          //do something}
}
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
The image and the directory are not in the jar. They are on the file system. And the paths are absolute paths to the image and the directory.

Comment: Show an example of jar invocation with paths to images, not just `inputX`

Comment: `java -jar myJar.jar /Users/abcd/image.jpg /Users/xyz -r output.jpg`

Comment: Do the image and directory in input1 and input2 exist within the jar, or are they on the filesystem?

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println("file1: " + file1.getCanonicalPath());` and the same for file2; just to make sure the program is looking for the files you think it is.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Actually the part of code posted works pretty well. Guess there is something wrong with the paths passed to the jar.